# Can change clusterip to nodeport command line without editor?

Tags: kubernetes

NodePort
This way of accessing Dashboard is only recommended for development environments in a single node setup.

Edit kubernetes-dashboard service.

$ kubectl -n kube-system edit service kubernetes-dashboard
You should see yaml representation of the service. Change type: ClusterIP to type: NodePort and save file.

Can change clusterip to nodeport command line without editor?
Thanks!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

you can change it like this

```
kubectl patch svc kubernetes-dashboard --type='json' -p '[{"op":"replace","path":"/spec/type","value":"NodePort"}]'
```

Comment: use --namespace=kube-system else it throws Error from server (NotFound): deployments.extensions "kubernetes-dashboard" not found

Answer (score 16):

`kubectl patch svc you-svc -p '{"spec": {"type": "NodePort"}}'`

Comment: the best answer here

Comment: For me it shows: `Error from server (BadRequest): invalid character 's' looking for beginning of object key string`

Comment: @VijayNirmal could please paste you command here

Comment: @袁文涛 Here is the exact command `kubectl patch svc kiali -n istio-system -p '{"spec": {"type": "NodePort"}}'`

Answer (score 13):

To specify a given nodePort in addition:

```
kubectl patch svc my-service --type='json' -p '[{"op":"replace","path":"/spec/type","value":"NodePort"},{"op":"replace","path":"/spec/ports/0/nodePort","value":30040}]'
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the answer for the reverse scenario of converting from NodePort to ClusterIP.

```
kubectl patch svc my-service --type='json' -p '[{"op":"replace","path":"/spec/type","value":"ClusterIP"},{"op":"replace","path":"/spec/ports/0/nodePort","value":null}]'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just fetch the YAML for this given service:

```
kubectl -n kube-system get service kubernetes-dashboard -o yaml > kube-dash-svc.yaml
```

Make the changes you want (without using an editor).
e.g.,

```
sed 's/ClusterIP/NodePort/' kube-dash-svc.yaml > new-kube-dash-svc.yaml
```

Delete the current service:

```
kubectl delete svc kubernetes-dashboard
```

And finally feed this yaml back to the Kubernetes control plane:

```
kubectl create -f new-kube-dash-svc.yaml
```

Comment: kubectl delete svc kubernetes-dashboard --namespace kube-system

Comment: Oh @software-engineer, pardon me.
I guess if we're being very strict about the "without an editor" requirement, with `sed` being a stream editor, then that does not qualify as a valid answer.
Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: You can just do this with an apply -f instead of delete & create !